# About 'Adobe Flash plugin' in software center

Tags: flash

In software center I find I do not install 'flash plugin'. But I still can see flash in firefox. What is the matter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two packages for installing flashplugin. The packages are called `flashplugin-installer` and `adobe-flashplugin`. `adobe-flashplugin` package is present in [Partner Repository](http://archive.canonical.com/) which is not enabled by default. While `flashplugin-installer` is present in `multiverse` repository but uses partner repository to download the source from package `adobe-flashplugin` as a post-install hook. If you installed `ubuntu-restricted-addons` metapackage. This package recommend `flashplugin-installer` and install it which may be your case.

[More on available repositories and how to enable them.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

May be you have selected installation of restricted software during OS installation