# Help w/ Adobe Flash installation

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [About 'Adobe Flash plugin' in software center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115295/about-adobe-flash-plugin-in-software-center)

I am trying to download Adobe Flash and I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. Help.

Answer (score 2):

see this answer here for details https://askubuntu.com/a/115308/46312

There are two packages for installing flashplugin. The packages are called flashplugin-installer and adobe-flashplugin

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can download the tar.gz directly from 
http://get.adobe.com/it/flashplayer/ and put it in the right plugin folder (i.e. for mozilla ~/.mozilla/plugins/)

Comment: True, but it will only be available to that user.